# Why is Core Data faster than SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have a very basic question for iPhone dev. Why is Core Data faster than SQLite even though CoreData uses SQLite under the hood?

Comment: What makes you think Core Data is faster than SQLite?

Comment: The selected answer might help you understand why.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045238/core-data-vs-sqlite-and-performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is in the optimisations that Apple has put in place in Core Data. It makes very intelligent decisions about items that should be cached for example.

Theoretically you could probably achieve the same performance without using Core Data, but it would take a very long time to re-build all of the optimisations that Apple engineers, who are very familiar was the platform, have put in place.